# Find by id or by object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It's usal to see codes where a model `where` search in a foreign key is realized passing the whole object. For instance, search user exercises:

```
Exercise.where(user: user)
```

Another usual way to do that is:

```
Exercise.where(user_id: user.id)
```

Checking in console log, both querys search by the user id, but there is a "most recommended" way between both? If yes, why: more elegant, performatic?

Comment: I would use the `id` version. But they are the same thanks to rails magic.

Comment: If you have an association of `user has_many :exercises` I will suggest to use `user.exercises` over the above two queries

Comment: Yes @DeepakMahakale . The example in my question is only figurative (without a context), but you're right!

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's about something that we use without ask at first. It seems a reasonable doubt to me, and I couldn't answer for sure when someone asked to me. It's a simple and quick question, but unless explain me why, isn't irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose the first one

```
Exercise.where(user: user)
```

It is mainly stylistic preference but also if the users every become polymorphic on exercises this would work without any changes whereas the second option would need to be changed to the first.

The benchmarks i quickly did showed no real performance difference.

Comment: Nice catch, with the polymorphic relations. BUT you do not have always the user model loaded. So this would cause a second query.

Comment: It would however from above he already has the user object to be able to call user.id

Comment: yes, I know. But I figured this was a more general question

Comment: Yes, my example is exatcly what it looks like: I'm querying my Exercise model and using an object loaded whit the user. Thanks for the answer @hvenables!

Answer (score -2):

```
Exercise.where('user_id = ?', user.id)
```

Not sure I understood your question correctly, but if you are looking for other ways to query or rather best practices then above is the right way to query in Rails.

The reason it is accepted as best practices is because its a Rails Security Countermeasure

[Rails Guides: Array Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)

[Rails Security Guides: SQL Injections: Countermeasures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection-countermeasures)

So to answer your question, yes there is good reasoning behind querying this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems weird. `Exercise.where(user_id: user.id)` look likes cleaner to me (: My question is simple: between both ways I shown, what is better and why (if they aren't the same)?

Comment: this works as well, but of the 3 versions, this is the worst

Comment: Yeah well.. as they say.. there is more than 1 way to solve a problem! Its developer preferences really.

Comment: ??? No! As stated in your links you can also use hashes. What you should NOT do is Exercise.where("user_id = #{params[:user_id]}")